# determining which DLLs are in memory

Tags: winapi, dll, vb6

I have a problem with a VB6 DLL and some of the behaviour leads me to wonder whether Windows is unloading it from memory after a period of inactivity. Are there any good applications/techniques for determining which DLLs are loaded into memory at a given point?

I'm using Windows XP if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4):

**Msinfo32.exe (quick)**

> Use Msinfo32.exe by hitting run then
>   entering Msinfo32.exe. Then, to see
>   DLLs are loaded into a memory, select
>   Software Environment then Loaded
>   Modules category from the bottom of
>   the left pane. Each item from the
>   Loaded Modules category represents an
>   application extension or a system
>   resource that is currently loaded in
>   memory. The right pane lists the DLL
>   name, fully qualified path to all
>   modules (drivers, fonts, dynamic link
>   libraries and executable files),
>   process, DLL version, size, date and
>   manufacturer in memory.

**Sysinternals Process Explorer (free / more robust)**

> Process Explorer is a GUI/device
>   driver combination that together shows
>   information about which handles and
>   DLL processes have opened and loaded
>   in memory. The unique capabilities of
>   Process Explorer make it useful for
>   tracking down DLL version problems or
>   handle leaks, and provide insight into
>   the way Windows and applications work
>   and more.

[Sysinternals Process explorerer download site](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)

Good article where i got the quoted info: [here](http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=47857)

Answer (score 0):

Download [ProcessXP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx). You can see exactly which DLLs a process has hooks open to (along with files, etc.).